# Is it a valid line in "Girls & Boys"?

Tags: code-golf, string, decision-problem, parsing, natural-language

### Intro

Blur's song *Girls & Boys* featured the lines

```
girls who are boys who like boys to be girls
who do boys like they're girls, who do girls like they're boys
```

in the chorus. These lines have a pretty uniform structure: you have a subject, which is either `girls` or `boys`, a relative clause, either `who are`, `who like`, or `who do`, an object, again either `girls` or `boys`, and an optional modifier, which is similar to the relative clause, except it can also be `like they're` or `to be`. In EBNF this might be written as:

```
subject ::= "boys" | "girls"
relative_clause ::= "who are" | "who like" | "who do"
modifier ::= relative_clause | "like theyre" | "to be"
tail ::= relative_clause subject (modifier sentence)?
sentence ::= subject tail
```

### The challenge

Your task is to, given a string, see if it is valid in this format. you can assume the string will be all lowercase, and will contain only letters and spaces (this means that `theyre` will have no apostrophe). It should output a boolean value or `0`/`1`. input and output can be done with any of the [standard I/O methods](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods). the input string may be empty. all words will be separated by a single space, but they will not all be valid words. for example, the input will never be `girls   who    likeboys` but it might be `girls who like bananas`

### Example I/O

```
girls who are boys who like boys to be girls who do boys like theyre girls who do girls like theyre boys -> true

boys who like boys -> true
true

girls to be boys -> false
`to be` is only valid in the modifier position, not as the leading relative clause.

girls who like boys to be girls to be boys -> false
The second `to be` is used in the relative clause position here, since after the first `to be` a new sentence begins, and sentences can't use modifiers in the relative clause position.

boys -> false

boys who are -> false

who are boys -> false

boys boys -> false

<empty input> -> false
```

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in characters wins.

Comment: Are you sure you want to score in characters? Our site standard is to use bytes for a good reason.

Comment: By the way, we strongly recommend to post your challenges in [the sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?answertab=active) to get feedback like this before posting them on the main site

Comment: Must matching be case-sensitive? Can we assume input is always lowercase?

Comment: @pxeger yes, you can assume input is always lowercase

Comment: Should `tail ::= relative_clause (subject modifier)? sentence` instead?

Comment: Actually that still doesn't work, because it doesn't allow the sentence to end in `like theyre boys`.

Comment: @Neil `(modifier? (subject | sentence))` maybe?

Comment: May the input contain words other than _are, be, boys, do, girls, like, theyre, to, who_?

Comment: Also, may we take the input as a list of words?

Comment: @Arnauld yes, it may contain other words, in which case you would just return false, and yes, you may take input as a list of words

Comment: Might want to fix the incorrect lyrics (should be 'Girls who want boys' not 'Girls who are boys') - although it makes no real difference to the code...

Comment: May I ignore extra spaces between tokens as your EBNF does not includes spaces in it. For example, both `"boyswho areboys"` and `"boys   who are      boys"` are valid. Or may I assume the input only contains valid tokens and separated by single space?

Comment: May I assume input is non-empty? Or maybe you can include a testcase for empty input.

Comment: Suggested testcases: `"boys" -> false`; `"boys who are" -> false`; `"who are boys" -> false`; `"boys boys" -> false`. Also it would be better to [layout testcases more friendly](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8101/44718).

Comment: @tsh you can assume the input contains only words seperated by a single space, i'll specify that. you cannot assume input is non-empty, i'll add a testcase for that and for your other suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 99 bytes

```
^(boy|girl)s( who (are|like|do) (boy|girl)s( (who (are|like|do)|like theyre|to be) (boy|girl)s)?)+$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wP04jKb@yJj2zKEezWEOhPCNfQSOxKLUmJzM7tSYlX1MBRVoDQx7MUCjJSK0ECpbkKySlomjRtNfUVvn/H8QpBhsO1KsAlIZwwHrBPLBOBYSylHyIOJLpqLIQDrI0SD0XptFcEJUQC5AEcNuPUAoA) Link includes test cases. Simply the grammar turned into a regex and optimised slightly.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `(-p)`, <s>82</s>, 80 bytes

From @Neil's Retina answer, but using recursive regex.

-2 thanks to @DomHastings.

```perl
$_=/^(boys|girls)( (who (are|like|do)) (?1)( ((?3)|like theyre|to be) (?1))?)+$/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY1BCsIwEEX3PcUsuphBpIi4lNxEsTTYYHBCEpBCzm5sJotGxOX//80bp7095dxfz8MFR15CuhtvAyHga2bAm9fJmodOExMBqkNZUB1JWoizXlYiMoy6zqRo1w85iwaKY1VAMUuQK0lyAxs2ce0b7/daQzsXvvtVd5WsD5ri//8NfbOLhp8h7637AA)

Comment: Nice work! You can save another couple of bytes too, grouping the `who (...)` as `(?3)`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY1BCsIwEEX3PcUsuphBpIi4lNxEsTTYYHBCEpBCzm5sJotGxOX//80bp7095dxfz8MFR15CuhtvAyHga2bAm9fJmodOExMBqkNZUB1JWoizXlYiMoy6zqRo1w85iwaKY1VAMUuQK0lyAxs2ce0b7/daQzsXvvtVd5WsD5ri//8NfbOLhp8h7637AA "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## [PEG.js](https://pegjs.org/), 92 bytes

```
S=s r" "s(m" "S)?
s="boys"/"girls"
r=" who "("are"/"like"/"do")
m=r/" like theyare"/" to be"
```

https://pegjs.org/online